# Debug multiple files in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, vscode-debugger

I've recently experimented with the debbuging tools in vscode. Everything seems to be working fine, I've set up the launch.json and set my program property. The problem is, breakpoints only work in the index.ts file, and I've got a commands folder as well with a file called champion.ts, in which the breakpoints stay as unbound. How can I make vscode debug those files aswell?

File structure

```
myapp/
├─ commands/
│  ├─ champion.ts
├─ index.ts
├─ out/
│  ├─ commands/
│  │  ├─ champion.js
│  ├─ index.js
```

launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.ts",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the glob in the `outFiles` array in your `launch.json` so that it also includes javascript (and, implicitly, source maps) that are located in subdirectories of the `out` directory (e.g. `out/commands/...`, etc.)

Instead of...

```
 "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/out/*.js"]
```

...write...

```
 "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"]
```

See [this example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_source-map-discovery) in the VSCode documentation.